# Android app interacting/doing stuff on a website

Tags: android, android-webview

First of all, i'm not that experienced a developer with android.

I recently started an project and for said project I need my app to interact with a website. Specifically I need my app to go to the page "http://tref.cals.nl/roosters/infoweb/index.php" and there auto-fill in the two text-boxes (html forms input type text to be exact) and log in. 
After that it should 'click' a link to download a file and use that file later in the app.

I've looked for all kinds of solutions, but can't really find anything that I think could help. I hope on receiving solutions, or something to look for.

If there is something else you need to know to answer my question feel free to ask.

EDIT:Thanks for the answer, but sadly i must inform you that i don't own the site in question. Also I can not arrange anything with the owner. That is why I thought of my way to do it. Anyway thanks for answering and I'm sorry I that I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: use some http sniffer(fx.: fiddler) and check what is browser sends to the server with "click" ... then do the same in android app using some http client (fx.: Apache, HTTPConnection, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The way you described might not be the most ideal way to achieve that you want.

I would recommend using some sort of api interface. Since you have a website, i assume you have a hosting service; you would need to create some sort of API request with username and password; which in turn responds with the url of a file. You could use androids asynchronous http request to do this

I would imagine it to flow something like this

1. Make a request to a url, which will reside on your website. You can post username and password to this url. `Ex: http://yoururl.com/api/validateuser.php`
2. Your API URL will return a download link or whatever you seem fit - using JSON or XML, or if it is just a URL, plain text should do too.
3. Use android's HTTP library or you can even use `aquery` to download this file to your local disk.

Reference:

```
AQuery
```

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

```
Async HTTP
```

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
Writing an API Tutorial
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/